# Personal google play books, how to make them voice-readable?

Tags: pdf, text-to-speech, ebooks, google-play-books

I am trying to load a couple of personal ebooks on my google play account, so that they are readable by google play books. The books are DRM-free, also.

Is there any way, to make them voice-readable? If not, what are the prerequisites? To all my tries till now, the "read aloud" option is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Google's [Text-to-Speech](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tts&hl=en) app from the playstore. It allows you to read text on the screen aloud by using the device's text-to-speech feature.

**Features:** 
As mentioned in the description, it can be used by:

• Google Play Books to “Read Aloud” your favourite book.

• Google Translate to speak translations aloud so you can hear the pronunciation of a word.

• TalkBack and accessibility applications for spoken feedback across your device.

• And many other applications in Play Store

**How to use?**

To use Google Text-to-speech on your Android device, go to `Settings > Language & Input > Text-to-speech` output. Select `Google Text-to-speech Engine` as your preferred engine.

[image: Screenshot]

<sub>Text-to-Speech Screenshot - Click to enlarge image</sub>

To start listening to books:

- Open the Google Play Books app Google Play Books app.
- Open a book.
- Touch the center of your screen.
- Touch Menu Menu > Read aloud.

Many books from Google Play can be read aloud. If you don't see the "Read aloud" option, that means the book is in a format that doesn't allow it. [Learn more about file types that allow reading aloud](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1062502).

Comment: Your link is unrelated to file types with tts